# configuring port forwarding on multiple routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, routing

Alright, so I have 2 routers.
My secondary router (netis) is connected to the primary router(ZTE) (through which the internet connection is coming) via LAN. All the devices directly connect to the secondary router (it basically acts as an access point).

Previously, using a single router, I had assigned a fixed IP to my mac address of the wifi adapter and forwarded 3 ports for the IP `192.168.1.5`. Now that I have two routers, the **secondary router** assigns the IP `192.168.1.5` to my computer and is connected to the **primary one** on `192.168.1.2`.

So, I forwarded the same three ports on my **secondary router** for the IP `192.168.1.5` (this is the ipv4 of my computer to the **secondary router**) however I am not able to access my web server any more through a different internet connection. I realized that the ports need to be forwarded through my **primary router**, but I tried doing that, and it still doesn't work.

This is my configuration so far on the **primary router**

[image]

And this is the configuration on my **secondary router** (The one which my computer is connected to)

[image]

It's an apache server running via xampp. It worked perfectly fine before, but since I've changed both routers, I need help configuring it properly. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Are you saying both routers are on the same subnet?  Not a good idea.

Comment: I think so, why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Let's start with some basics... are the two routers connected to each other via LAN ports, or WAN to LAN?

Comment: via LAN ports..

Comment: Ok, then you don't need to be port-forwarding through both routers.  Just change your primary router to forward to your server (.5)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AMMMy.png
And it still doesn't work....

Comment: And I've changed that one to 192.168.1.5

Comment: I've done it!! Yayy! Basically, just had to forward my secondary's router IP (192.168.1.3)

Comment: Does the primary router support DMZ? If it does then you can probably put the second router in it and then you'd only need to configure that router.

Comment: Your question never mentioned .3... you implied your primary router was .1 and your secondary .2 and your server .5

Comment: Nope, but I'll have you know that I had to forward it from my secondary router as well, (the connection is then forwarded to my primary), and now I can successfully connect.

Comment: it was .3, I checked it wrong. .2 was the default gateway. But that doesn't matter in this scenario, as the problem would've existed either way. It's the order of configuration.

Comment: @Jason i'd be interested, what are the technical differences between connecting two routers WAN-WAN vs LAN-LAN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On behalf of Gandalf's Beard, solution from comment: I had to forward my secondary's router IP (192.168.1.3).